# Issue with Android and Facebook login Integration

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am facing a very strange issue while leveraging Facebook login in my android apppication. Presently I am in development stage therefore am using development hash key for login. However, the hash key works only once because in all subsequent attempts facebook prompts an error "***Invalid key hash. The key hash <27 characters with last character chipped off***> does not match any stored key hashes".

Surprisingly, last character of the hash key is chipped off in all subsequent attempts. When I view the key using the code below then all 28 characters are displayed. Please help.

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

28 character key = **bQ+yCvQFF8KaTt5Da7PG/PftMKs=**

facebook receives = **bQ+yCvQFF8KaTt5Da7PG/PftMKs** (without the last "=" character)

Please help

Comment: did you check for white space at staring of key? bQ+yCvQFF8KaTt5Da7PG/PftMKs= is correct it should be accepted

Comment: I did check but as I said earlier login does happen but only once. All subsequent attemps fail